# Cannot fetch array of strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, graphql

Hello i'm trying to fetch some data in my mongoDB collections through graphQL,

Here's my graphQl schema :

```js
type Account {
  _id: String
  id: String
  account_id: Int
  limit: Int!
  products: [String]
}

type Query {
  account(_id: String): [Account]
}
```

Here's a console log of the resolver return

```
[ { _id: 5ca4bbc7a2dd94ee58162a49,
    account_id: 142442,
    limit: 9000,
    products:
     [ 'Commodity',
       'CurrencyService',
       'Derivatives',
       'InvestmentFund',
       'InvestmentStock' ],
    id: '5ca4bbc7a2dd94ee58162a49' } ]
```

but here's the query returns from graphiQL

```js
{
  "data": {
    "account": [
      {
        "id": "5ca4bbc7a2dd94ee58162a49",
        "_id": "5ca4bbc7a2dd94ee58162a49",
        "account_id": null,
        "limit": 9000,
        "products": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can't figure out why my products and account_id fields return a null value, they seems to have the correct type, did i miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay nevermind the problem was in the mongoose schema i forgot to add these fields

```js
const accounts = new Schema({
    limit: Number,
    products: [String],
    account_id: Number
})
```